# Accessing Original Property Value from `__defineGetter__`

Tags: javascript, oop

Is it possible to access the original property value from a Javascript getter?

If not, are there other "modern" javascript techniques for achieving something similar?

That is, if I have code like this

```
o = {}
o.foo = "bar"
o.__defineGetter__("foo", function(){
    //can I access the value "bar" here?
    return "some other value";
});
```

Is it possible to access the value "bar" from within my getter function?  Or does using `__defineGetter__` blow away the property?

(Context: not a newbie developer, but I've been ignoring non-cross-browser Javascript for the past 4/5 years and I'm looking to catch up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECMAscript 262 edition 5 introduced the option for having *getters* and *setters* on objects officially defined by spec. You can setup those either directly on an object literal

```
var foo = {
    get bar() {
        return "foo";
    }
};
```

or using `Object.defineProperty()`

```
var foo = { };
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
    get: function() {
        return "foo";
    }
});
```

However, the problem remains the same. Overwritting a property will irrepealable overwrite it. What you can do, is use the objects `prototype chain` to gleam properties.

---

```
var foo = { };

foo.bar = 42;

Object.defineProperty(Object.getPrototypeOf( foo ), 'bar', {
    get: function() {
        return 'overwritten';
    },
    configurable: true
});

console.log( foo.bar );   // 42
delete foo.bar;
console.log( foo.bar );   // "overwritten"
```

Comment: is `__proto__` part of a standard now?

Comment: @JuanMendes: at least every browser that supports ES5 supports that property. You can of course also call `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead.

Comment: @jAndy: Opera supports ES5.1, but has no `__proto__`. Use the standard `Object.getPrototypeOf`

Comment: @Bergi: oh, didn't know that. I just have to trust you, never really used Opera.

Answer (score 1):

No, [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) (as well as [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)) overwrites everything old. You'd have to cache the old value in an extra variable before "*blowing away the property*".

Using an IEFE as a closure:

```
o = {foo: "bar"};

(function(oldval) {
    o.__defineGetter__("foo", function(){
        return "new"+oldval;
    });
})(o.foo);
o.foo; // "newbar"
```

Answer (score 1):

The __defineGetter__ is like a shortcut for

```
Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", {get : function() { 
        return "some other value";
    },  
    enumerable : true});
```

So the **o.foo** value is simply overwritten. To solve this problem add additional property **o._foo** and don't forget about setter.

My example:

```
var o = {};

Object.defineProperty(o, "foo", {
    get : function() { 
        return this._foo;
    },
    set : function(value) { 
        this._foo = value;
    },
    enumerable : true});

o.foo = "newbar";
o.foo;  //newbar
```